# Yahoo Ticker API no longer real-time

Tags: javascript, finance, yahoo-finance, stockquotes

We have been using the yahoo rest api for years to get the current stock price for our company.

Just noticed that it now provides the last closing price (i.e.  if checking at 11:00, it gives the price  at 4pm the previous day.

Does anyone have a workaround?  Or maybe a different rest api from someone besides yahoo???

All inputs appreciated!

example: http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=tsla&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgvj1pp2owern&e=.csv

Comment: http://www.programmableweb.com/category/stocks/apis?category=20137

Comment: While it will not solve your current problem, you might want to take a look at this page: http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm

Answer (score 1):

Found one here:

http://www.programmableweb.com/api/stock-quote 
http://dev.markitondemand.com/#doc_lookup

Probably not 100% real time, but close enough.

Example:
http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=myFunction

Comment: This is giving previous day quotes.